# rsync: Permission denied (publickey) with SSH

Tags: linux, ssh, permissions, rsync, cron

I have a server on which I connect in SSH with my key files such as `id_rsa.pub`. 
I am using Debian on client and server side.

I followed a tutorial to disable root authentication and password use for more security (by configuring the `/etc/ssh/sshd/sshd_config` file on the server).

Until now, I could easily use `rsync` to synchronize my files from my computer to the server.

A few days ago,  [I used a cron job](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1151393/youtube-dl-in-a-crontab-displays-errno-13-permission-denied) job and for that I had to reset my root password on the server side.

Since then, it has been impossible for me to use `rsync` in `SSH`;
I get the following message:

```
nextcloud@192.168.0.20: Permission denied (publickey).
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far)[sender]
rsync error: unexplained error (code 255) at io.c(235)[sender=3.1.3]
```

There are some similar topics, but I think my case is a bit different because I think the problem is due to resetting my password on the server. I have also asked a question on the Ask Ubuntu site,
but I think maybe people here are more expert in permission issues.

I have no idea how to fix the problem (I manage a little bit in terminal commands, but I'm not a computer expert). Could you help me, please?

*For Your Information only, please find the tutorial tweaking the `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` to not use password:*

```
#Uncomment or add the following line. 
#This allows the server to give its DSA footprint in case of an ssh connection.
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key

#Then set the next parameter to 20s (for example). 
#This is the time during which a connection without being logged in will be opened. 
#If we had kept the good old password technique, leave 2 or 3 minutes to type it, it's not too much. 
#But since we're using the key now, we'll be logged in immediately. #So we can really reduce the thing and put it down to 20 seconds for example.
LoginGraceTime 20s

#this is the maximum number of attempts before being thrown by the server.... 
#Since with the key, no possible error, you can put it to 1 possible test.
MaxAuthTries 1

#Then, we will tell the SSH server where the keys are and tell it that we will use them as an authentication method
PubkeyAuthentication yes
AuthorizedKeysFile.ssh/authorized_keys

#And of course, we'll disable all other authentication methods
RSAAuthentication no.
UsePAM no
KerberosAuthentication no
GSSAPIA Authentication no.
PasswordAuthentication no

#Then, we will tell that we only allow users of the sshusers group (for more security)
AllowGroups sshusers

#The MaxStartups setting indicates the number of un-authenticated ssh connections you can launch at the same time. 
#2 is more than enough, knowing that with the keys, it's instantaneous.
MaxStartups 2
```

Comment: Did you change your unix password or the passpgrase on your key?

Comment: Yes I have updated my server root password with `sudo passwd root`

Comment: I think the password is a red herring. Most likely something you have done (maybe related to your cron job) has caused sshd to stop, or be firewalled so its unreachable.

Comment: @davidgo : thank you, so you think it's not related to the password but rather to the cronjob? This would explain why I am able to connect in SSH but it is impossible for me to transfer files. I'm thinking about a permission problem (chmod type), what do you think? Thank you. Thank you.

Comment: can you ssh as nextcloud?

Comment: Yes, I can ssh to my server as nextcloud. Only rsync through ssh (from my computer to my server) doesn't work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Oh no!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hsNG6.jpg)

I just found the solution... 
My command was:

```
sudo rsync -avz -e "ssh -p <port>" <source> <destination>
```

But I had to do it simply (without `sudo`):

```
rsync -avz -e "ssh -p <port>" <source> <destination>
```

I'm not sure about the cause, but I think that the `root` user of my desktop computer was not allowed to access my server in SSH since the key was only for my `classic` Desktop user (so without sudo).

Can anyone please confirm? Thank you.

Comment: That sounds right.  SSH would, by default look on the users home/.ssh for private key. Any reason tjis needs to be run as root?

Comment: What you say is very logical, I should have thought about it.. I have no particular reason to use `sudo` privileges for this ssh file transfer. It's a reflex, yet I don't usually abuse `sudo`. I really appreciate the help you gave me until the end. Thank you very much @davidgo !

Comment: `Can anyone please confirm?` CONFIRMED! Thank you, @prog-amateur! You nailed it! It too me *forever* to figure out what was going on here, as my ssh key was loaded in my ssh-agent via `ssh-add /path/to/priv/key` and I didn't know why it wasn't working.

Comment: @davidgo, I need to use `sudo` because I am rsyncing some root files too which are readable only by root.

Comment: Ex: `/root` is not readable by anyone but root, yet I'd like to back it up to an external drive connected to a remote server, using `rsync`. This puts me in a conundrum: I need to use `sudo` to access the `/root` dir, yet I need to NOT use `sudo` because that breaks the `ssh-agent`. Not sure what to do to solve this...